# How to set up a stack for Android SDK 33?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, build-tools

For context I use Cordova.

I have installed build tools 33.0.0 from Android Studio, Gradle version 7.6 and changed my environment variables. My Gradle is located at C:\gradle.

I have gone into the `7.6/bin` folder and ran gradle.bat, ran the command `gradle -v` at the command prompt to ensure it is correct,

I changed my config.xml file to say `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="33" />` without the quotes,

I created an emulator that has Tiramisu as System image, and restarted my physical machine.

When I run: `cordova platform add android@12.0.0` it build fine with the Android Target SKD: android-33 and Android Compile SDK:33

Here is my plugin list just in case: at.modalog.cordova.plugin.cache 1.1.0 "Cache"

- cordova-plugin-advanced-http 3.3.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
- cordova-plugin-camera 6.0.0 "Camera"
- cordova-plugin-device 2.1.0 "Device"
- cordova-plugin-dialogs 2.0.2 "Notification"
- cordova-plugin-file 7.0.0 "File"
- cordova-plugin-firebasex 16.0.0 "Google Firebase Plugin"
- cordova-plugin-native-settings 1.0.0 "NativeSettings"
- cordova-plugin-statusbar 3.0.0 "StatusBar"
- cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 6.0.4 "SocialSharing"
- es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
- ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"

I tried to run: `cordova run android`

and I get

```
C:\Users\*****an\APP_DEV\******_APP\APP>cordova run android
cordova-plugin-firebasex: Preparing Firebase on Android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\*****an\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\*****an\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\*****an\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 990ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app

> Configure project :app
strippedNativeLibsDir is deprecated and no longer used. Please remove it from your build configuration.

> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript
The RenderScript APIs are deprecated. They will be removed in Android Gradle plugin 9.0. See the following link for a guide to migrate from RenderScript: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/migrate

> Task :app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
> Error while evaluating property 'extraGeneratedResDir' of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of task ':app:mapDebugSourceSetPaths' property 'extraGeneratedResDir'.
      > Querying the mapped value of provider(java.util.Set) before task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' has completed is not supported

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 3s
11 actionable tasks: 11 executed
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\*****an\APP_DEV\******_APP\APP\platforms\android\gradlew -b C:\Users\*****an\APP_DEV\******_APP\APP\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug
```

And yes I have tried: gradle --stacktrace   and got nowhere trying to do what it "suggests"

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the point of stack overflow. We are not here to guide you. If you have a specific question with a problem that you're having, you can ask a pointed and specific question. But if you are looking for someone to hold your hand step by step setting up an application, you might have better luck in a Discord server or by simply watching Youtube tutorials.

Comment: Well if that is the case, is there an obvious error I am making?  Or a not so obvious error?

Comment: @Partyrock66 , you need to check the used plugins. The error comes by using different versions of libraries, that are into the plugins. Some of there plugins was updated recently, other had no update for years. You need to find the versions, where all target same libraries versions (that are into the plugins itself). More as that we cannot help

Answer (score 1):

I got it all figured out.
build tools 32.0.0, gradle 7.6, android-minSdkVersion =24, android-targetSdkVersion =33, android studio version Giraffe 2022.3.1 Patch 1, cordova-plugin-firebasex 16.1.0, emulator made with/ Android 13.0 Google Play

Just in case anyone else ever needs help and uses cordova.